# How to append column from reference table? (laravel)

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-5.8

I'm having trouble of appending column from other table(referenced). In my case I have `User.php` model and `UserContact.php` model.

**create_user_contacts_table**

```
Schema::create('user_contacts', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->bigIncrements('id');
    $table->unsignedBigInteger('user_id');
    $table->char('phone_no')->nullable();
    $table->char('telephone_no')->nullable();

    $table->foreign('user_id')
        ->references('id')
        ->on('users');
});
```

---

Here's the problem. I would like to append the `email` column from `users` table to my `user_contacts` table. I tried to `UserContact::all();` but it doesn't work and it ends an error:

> Maximum execution time of 60 seconds exceeded

**UserContact.php**

```
class UserContact extends Model
{
    //fillables

    public function user()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\User');
    }

    protected $appends = ['email'];

    public function getEmailAttribute()
    {
        return $this->user->email;
    }
}
```

---

But when I tried these below it is working.

```
$u = UserContact::first();
$u->user->email;
```

Someone knows how to achieve this thing?

Comment: If you do `UserContact::first()->email;` it s doesn't work?

Comment: @porloscerrosΨ still doesn't work.

Comment: why should you append another column? if you give it relationship then you can access user email using user_id.

Comment: @sajadHaibat yeah I know, but isn't it easy to `$contact->email` than `$contact->user->email`? In addition, there's a lot of method that I'm applying to that not just `getEmailAttribute` method. thanks for reply.